# Disable ssl certificate validation in mechanize

Tags: python, ssl, mechanize

I am new to python and I was trying to access a website using mechanize.

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
r=br.open("https://172.22.2.2/")
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    br.open("https://172.22.2.2/")
  File "/home/freeza/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/freeza/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 230, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "/home/freeza/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_opener.py", line 193, in open
    response = urlopen(self, req, data)
  File "/home/freeza/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 344, in _open
'_open', req)
  File "/home/freeza/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 332, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/freeza/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 1170, in https_open
    return self.do_open(conn_factory, req)
  File "/home/freeza/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 1118, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

Can you tell me how to disable ssl certificate validation in mechanize in python?

Also can you tell me how to include certificate if I get it?
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this code snippet to disable HTTPS certificate validation before br.open().

```
import ssl
try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    # Legacy Python that doesn't verify HTTPS certificates by default
    pass
else:
    # Handle target environment that doesn't support HTTPS verification
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```

For people asking for explanation: check this [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/#opting-out).

Comment: Can you explain what it does exactly??

Comment: I would also really like to know what this does :)